# Rabbitmq dead letter queue not delaying message

Tags: ruby, rabbitmq, bunny

I have setup rabbitmq. I want to retry message after 10 second once they fail. But the way I have setup, the message is not getting delayed, it's coming back to queue immediately. I want to wait 10 second before sending message to `main_queue`.

Below are my code. I am using Bunny Ruby gem.

```
connection = Bunny.new('url_for_rabbitmq', verify_peer: true)
connection.start
channel = connection.create_channel

# Creating 2 Exchanges (One Main exchange, one retry exchange)

exchange = channel.direct('main_exchange')
retry_exchange = channel.direct('retry_exchange')

# Creating 2 Queue (One Main queue, one retry queue)

queue = channel.queue('main_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => retry_exchange.name })
queue.bind(exchange, routing_key: 'foo')
queue.bind(retry_exchange, routing_key: 'foo') # This one is pushing message directly to main queue without waiting for 10 second.

retry_queue = channel.queue('retry_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-message-ttl' => 10_1000, 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => retry_exchange.name })
retry_queue.bind(retry_exchange, routing_key: 'foo')
```

If i change this line (retry_exchange to exchange)

```
retry_queue = channel.queue('retry_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-message-ttl' => 10_1000, 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => retry_exchange.name })
```

to this

```
retry_queue = channel.queue('retry_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-message-ttl' => 10_1000, 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => exchange.name })
```

then it works. but the message is coming from `main_exchange` but I want message to come from `retry_exchange`. How can i achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I solve the problem

```
connection = Bunny.new('url_for_rabbitmq', verify_peer: true)
connection.start
channel = connection.create_channel

# Creating 2 Exchanges (One Main exchange, one retry exchange)

exchange = channel.direct('main_exchange')
retry_exchange = channel.direct('retry_exchange')

# Creating 2 Queue (One Main queue, one retry queue)

retry_queue = channel.queue('retry_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-message-ttl' => 10_1000, 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => retry_exchange.name })
retry_queue.bind(retry_exchange, routing_key: 'foo')
retry_queue.bind(retry_exchange, routing_key: retry_queue.name)


queue = channel.queue('main_queue', durable: true, arguments: { 'x-dead-letter-exchange' => retry_exchange.name, 'x-dead-letter-routing-key' => retry_queue.name })
queue.bind(exchange, routing_key: 'foo')
queue.bind(exchange, routing_key: retry_queue.name)
```

basically i needed to add this to main queue `'x-dead-letter-routing-key' => retry_queue.name`. and remove couple of unnecessary binding from main queue `queue.bind(retry_exchange, routing_key: 'foo')`

Now message come to main queue, if it fails then it goes to retry queue. Before going to retry queue, it will remove old routing key `foo` and replace it with new routing key `retry_queue.name`. It stays in retry queue for 10 seconds and then again come back to main queue for retry.